# Calculating the entropy of a quantum state

Tags: entropy, information-theory, linear-algebra

Let $\rho_{AR}$ be some $d-$dimensional pure quantum state. Consider a channel $N_{A\rightarrow B}$ that outputs a constant state in $B$. We now consider the Stinespring dilation of this channel with some environment register $E$ and trace out the $B$ register. This gives us the state below

$$\sigma_{RE} = \sum\limits_{k, k'=1}^{d} \langle k_A \vert \ \rho_{AR} \vert k'_A\ \rangle\otimes \vert k_E\rangle\langle k'_E \vert,$$

where $\vert k\rangle, \vert k'\rangle$ denote basis vectors from any fixed basis. How can one calculate the von Neumann entropy of $\sigma_{RE}$ given by $S(\sigma_{RE}) = \text{Tr}(\sigma_{RE}\log\sigma_{RE})$? I am unable to simplify my expression beyond the definition so any hints are appreciated. I would like to express the answer in terms of $S(\rho_R)$ (and maybe other terms as pointed out in the comment).

Comment: This will depend on more than $S(\rho_R)$.